# Qt UI Threading Problems

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

OK so i have asked a couple of questions specifically about QFuture which is what im currently using to thread my UI application.

Basically i have a function in a class that takes a long time so naturally i wanted it threaded so when called from my UI class it didnt just lock up my UI.

I then implemented a QFutureWatcher to wait for the finished() signal at which point it would start another function that took ages in a new thread (this one however was doing things to the UI). I used the same code to implement the second threaded function however this one still locks up my UI.

i have come to conclusions which may be entirely wrong but i cant seem to find out why its not working so all i can do is assume and ask here...

Maybe i cant have 2 QFuture's using QConcurrentRun

Cant use QFuture with ui stuff (in my case QGraphicsView adding to scene)

if anyone has suggestions that would be great, iv read in another post  i should maybe subclass QObject but no example was given so i couldnt really implement this because i didnt know what kind of functionality i was meant to even be re implementing ..

TLDR: HOW TO THREAD A FUNCTION THAT DOES THINGS TO UI (adding to QGraphicsScene)

code sample, this is the function that takes ages because i call this function from a different functions loop a few hundred thousand times, takes about 30 seconds to complete in which time the UI is not responding

```
void GUI::paintSomething(double x, double y)
{
    /// Decalre a QPen for Painting dots
    QPen pen;

    // set the pen colour
    pen.setColor(Qt::white);

    // Add ellipse at the x y position passed in
    scene->addEllipse(x, y, 1.5, 1.5, pen, QBrush(Qt::SolidPattern));
}
```

Thread code, paint all being the function that calls paintSomething

```
*future2 = QtConcurrent::run(this, &GUI::paintAll);

// Set watcher to look at QFuture futre2
watcher2->setFuture(*future2);
```

Comment: i honestly cant believe someone came by and grammar nazi'd this post instead of offering any help -.-

Comment: Your background thread should send signals that are connected to you UI thread to change the user interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly updating the ui / creating ui elements from anything but your main thread is a big no-no. So don't even go down that route.

To communicate between worker-threads and main threads, 
In Qt you can use a `Qt::QueuedConnection` when connecting cross-thread Signal <-> Slot.

What you'd normally intend to do is have your calculations in the worker-thread and when your at the point to create and add elements to the `QGraphicsView`, send a signal with whatever relevant info is required, Catch it in the Main thread and act accordingly.

**Update:**

Ok if your calling anything "few hundred thousand times" even if it's a single function call from the main thread in a span of about 30 seconds, your going to have performance loss. It's just what it boils down to. There is no magic trick to solving that since your limited by what hardware you've got and what it can deliver in a clock-cycle fundamentally.

What you need is to address your problem in a different way. Ask yourself what your `QGraphicsView` is rendering.

Is it maybe things you can cache into an Image?

Do all Few hundred thousand items need to be interactable?

You can also have a look at the ["Mandelbrot - Example"](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/threads-mandelbrot.html) that comes with Qt to see cross-thread updates are handled.

Comment: iv seen this before on some other posts but i really cant work out from docs what i need to do, im not asking you to give me full code but a small example would be really helpful if you wouldnt mind

Comment: sure but i think your problem here is not going to be solved with just updating the ui thread from the main thread correctly. It's one of the problems. I'll update my answer with some details.

Comment: Theres no problem with hardware at all its a high spec machine im using, the the process is finished a lot sooner than that (i can tell because i added some console logs) but the ui is still not responding for some time after completion. and what do you mean by irreplaceable

Comment: Yes your flushing stuff to get done but they still need to get rendered and while that is happening your event loop is hung and cannot process basic user interactions. I said "interactable" is that what you thought was "irreplaceable". Have a read through the Madelbrot example from the link in the answer. It shows you how to emit signals and action on heavy computation in a cross-thread fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's really bad practice - to update GUI thread from within worker thread and you should really do it via signal-slot, you still can update GUI via `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`

You have to run every function in a worker thread, that updates GUI through `invokeMethod()`. For example - your `void GUI::paintSomething(double x, double y)` will have to be invoked within the thread like this:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this,"paintSomething", Q_ARG(double,x), Q_ARG(double,y));
```

GUI will spot freezing, but this will definitely not increase your performance..

```
i call this function from a different functions loop a few hundred thousand times
```

when i did similar task - i didn't updated GUI after every single update, just a few time a second (QElapsedTimer) and did all the painting within QImage, which repainted on a QLabel after some timeout. Hope this helps

Comment: the thing is my function just adds an ellipse to the scene and the function that calls that is looping getting the x y values so it can pretty much only be called 1 at a time unless you can draw an ellipse to the scene without actually updating it ... and then update it on a timer with a few hundred dots each time?

Comment: also the invoke method things just keeps telling me theres no such method paintSomething(double,double) in this class when there clearly is? its declared like a normal function would be is that wrong or something?

Comment: it will not work, if you try to invoke method from another class, i assumed, that you will invoke `GUI::paintSomething` in GUI::paintAll or any other function in GUI class. If you invoke it in another class, you have to pass pointer to object instead of `this` as first argument. Here is a doc - http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod

Comment: About ellipses - you can draw them on QImage via QPainter and flush it to your scene (via `addPixmap()` for example) after all operations are done or after timeout of timer