# Signals and slots QT

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals

I have asked a number of different questions now all regarding one main issue in my program and still not solved it at all, I'm using threading to keep my UI from locking up, but basically it still does because apparently you can't do UI stuff in threads.

So I've been told to use custom signals and slots (not that any examples were given).

So from the documentation I've read I came up with this code:

.h

```
signals:

void paint_signal(double x, double y);
```

.cpp

```
  connect(this,SIGNAL(paint_signal(double x, double y)), this, SLOT(PaintSomething(x,y)));
```

the Paintsomething function is within the same class as all of this....

thread:

```
*future2 = QtConcurrent::run(this, &GUI::paintAll);
```

paint all emits the paint_signal and passes 2 doubles

```
emit paint_signal(x, y);
```

but I get this error which I just don't understand at all

```
 connect: No such signal GUI::paint_signal(double x, double y)
```

Comment: signals: void paint_signal(double x, double y);

Comment: sorry typo when i put my code in, its not that

Comment: Does your: .h class file extend QObject or QMainWindow?

Comment: neither its extends QWidget its just the class when you use Qt to make a QWidget application you get the class with all the ui setup its that class basically

Comment: do i have to have a definition of the signal in cpp? because thats where its saying there is no such signal... in the cpp file ...

Comment: @AngryDuck No. <char lim>

Comment: what? does that mean?

Comment: @AngryDuck "do i have to have a definition of the signal in cpp?" No. Clearer?

Comment: i meant the <char lim> bit but just nvm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
connect(this,
        SIGNAL(paint_signal(double, double)), 
        this, 
        SLOT(PaintSomething(x,y)));
```

Remove parameter names and it should work. If this one doesn't work this one will:

```
    connect(this,
        SIGNAL(paint_signal(double, double)), 
        this, 
        SLOT(PaintSomething(double,double)));
```

Let me know if this works out for you :)

**Update**

The idea is that you cannot use the UI in a thread, instead you emit signals from the thread to the UI. Because this answer probably gets you back to the beginning (and possibly a new question) here is a working example of how to emit signals from threads:

[QT Signals to UI in a thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Updating_GUI_from_QThread)

Comment: cheers yea this did work sadly didnt in anyway solve my issue though with the ui locking up i knew it wouldnt though because surely this is still within the thread so it makes no difference i called with a signal and a slot if threads cant do ui how was this any different and why was it suggested??

Comment: ok so the paintAll function is running in a thread, which emits a signal that signal is picked up and calls the function that adds to the QGraphicsScene which is not in the thread correct? but that function (adding to the QGraphcisScene) is the one thats taking ages and locking up my ui so thats what needs to be threaded this is what iv asked so many times now but seemingly no one can answer it

Comment: surely there must be a way to run this functionality in a thread? there must be other people who have had heavy UI functions and i refuse to believe you cant thread them #

Comment: do you know anyway this is possible because this is getting so annoying now its about the 5th question with no results :(

Comment: @AngryDuck So in your thread you have: the signal, the emit which are connected to a function in your non-thread class (the main window for example). You emit the signal from the thread and the function is taking ages(?) and locking up the ui? Where is that function located?

Comment: ok let me clear this up, everything is in the same class (these functions im refering to at least) `GUI.cpp` contains the QFuture which runs a function `paintALL` in GUI.cpp, `paintAll` emits a signal which is picked up which runs another function `paintSomething` in `GUI.cpp` so the `paintSomething` function is the one that takes ages and its locking my ui up because i assume its not running in a thread since its called from a signal from a function running in a different thread, i assume `paintSomething` is being called and running in the main thread which is not what i want

Comment: `paintSomething` is called hundreds of thousands of times from a loop in the function `paintAll`

Comment: @AngryDuck I would need to see your code to know what's going wrong. Could you post a new question as this is quite different from your original question?

Comment: i have a lot of questions regarding this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196608/qt-ui-threading-problems

Comment: if you could take a look and drop an answer there to discuss that would be great cheeers

Comment: Do you have a seperate class for your thread that extends QThread?

Comment: but i think i solved it now by adding all the points to a different scene and then just setting the new scene when its all done adding dots to it so setting a populates scene takes like 1 second instead of updating one im currently using which obviously locks the UI

Answer (score 1):

Floris Velleman's answer is ok, however by using the [new signal slot syntax](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax), you can catch errors during compile time and get rid of the redundant paranthesis.

**Old Syntax:**

```
connect(this,
        SIGNAL(paint_signal(double, double)), 
        this, 
        SLOT(PaintSomething(double,double)));
```

**New Syntax:**

```
connect(this,
        &SenderClass::paint_signal, 
        this, 
        &ReceiverClass::PaintSomething);
```